# API para desenvolvimento de Jogos para Android

Tags: android

Sou programador JAVA a um bom tempo, e agora quero expandir meus horizontes, já sei bastante coisas para android e queria saber por vocês uma boa API para iniciantes em android para games.

Comment: Olá, bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Os pedidos de recomendação de APIs ou ferramentas [são problemáticos](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57/devemos-aceitar-quest%C3%B5es-de-recomenda%C3%A7%C3%A3o) e não agradam a todos aqui no site. Se você fizer uma pesquisa sobre algumas APIs e fizer uma pergunta que contraste vantagens e desvantagens de 2 ou 3 deles, acho que teria uma recepção melhor.

Answer (score 2):

Tem a Cocos2D que serve tanto para IOS quanto Android

Segue link para livro.

http://www.casadocodigo.com.br/products/livro-jogos-android

Site

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/